# how to direct php curl through proxy by default

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm trying to set up a php project which use curl and my setup is behind a proxy. The script can access urls through proxy with the below set up.

```
$url = 'http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/ip.php';
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888';
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

But since I'm using a 3rd party script and I don't want to modify that script; **I want is to know if there is a way to set cURL to go through proxy by default.** some thing like

```
$opts = array('http' => array('request_fulluri' => true,
                          'proxy' => 'tcp://10.0.9.61:3128'),
        );
stream_context_get_default($opts);
```

which works for fopen or get_file_contents.

I looked through other threads but didn't find anything. Appreciate your help.

Comment: i also want a answer for this, hope someone will answer it

Comment: It's not ideal but you can use Proxifier or set HTTP_PROXY environment variable.